# How to implement two months calendar using android

Tags: android, android-calendar

> I want to implement two month calendar in my android application like below image,

[image]

i tried to get by googling but cant get any source code for two months calendar,Pls give source code for two months calendar if any... Awaiting for your replies...

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to implement two months calendar using the grid view. The main advantage of the grid view is , it having autoscroll property default.So try to use gridview on your android xml. Refer code below,

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/calendar"
    android:numColumns="7"      
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</GridView>
```